# Is frequency of 40 Hz light from Apple/Android tablet as reliable as that from an LED light?

Tags: led

On this site, I read about the MIT study using 40 Hz light and sound to mitigate the effects of Alzheimer's disease. I am looking for a suitable 40 Hz lighting device, even though the jury is still out on its efficacy in humans.

There are apps like [AlzLife](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=life.alz.alzlife&hl=en_US&gl=US) which flicker at 40 Hz gamma. However, I have read that the light from a tablet is less reliable than an LED light due to analog/digital issues.

I would be grateful if someone with knowledge could tell me whether this is correct.

Comment: I looked for the Alzlight app on iOS to try and measure it with a scope but couldn't find it.

Comment: @WesleyLee Why not just turn on a 40Hz flashing youtube video and measure that? I guess that would be subject to frame rate on top of the LCD refresh.

Comment: Arent youtube videos 24fps? or 60fps? I just wanted to measure the actual App the OP referred to, it would be more precise and to the point.

Comment: This app? Not sure how you were searching but "40hz flashing app" into Google came up with this as the first result https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=life.alz.alzlife&pcampaignid=pcampaignidMKT-Other-global-all-co-prtnr-py-PartBadge-Mar2515-1

Comment: The app is "alzlife" not "alzlight"... I looked for a phototransistor in my stash, no luck, tried a LED as a photodiode, but that picked up tons of EMI from the phone...

Comment: Hi Wesley, I typed the wrong name -- the app is called AlzLife like Bobflux noted. If there is any chance you could measure it, I would be very grateful. Thanks, Rob

Answer (score 1):

Its probably not because of the OS getting in the way (although they always get in the way when timing is important). 40Hz is so long compared to the processor clock speed I would think it would be fine. At 1GHz you could be off by 100,000 cycles and still be within 0.4%.of 40Hz.

Probably a bigger factor is the 60Hz-120Hz LCD refresh. 40Hz is a multiple of 120Hz so that might be okay, but other common  refresh rates, not so much.

Comment: Thank for the input. Rob